# How to exclude letters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using regular expressions in my code to check for a few letters/letter sequences.

This is my code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    // var str = "wr"; true
    // var str = "wR"; true
    // var str = "au"; true
    // var str = "u";  true
    // var str = "a";  true
    var str = "r";    // Must be false.
    alert(/[wr|wR|au|u|a]/.test(str));

}
</script>
```

As shown in the code it returns true for `wr`, `wR`, `au`, and `a`. As for `r`, and `R` it must be false.

But if I give `'r'` or `'R'` it is returning true instead of false!

I'm not that good at Regular Expressions. Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A character class (`[…]`) will match any single instance of any character (or range of characters) that you place in side it. If you want to use alternations (`|`), they must be outside of a character class:

```
alert(/wr|wR|au|u|a/.test(str));
```

Also, you might want to put it in a group (`(…)`) and use start (`^`) and stop (`$`) anchors around your pattern, otherwise, it would happily match the `a` in `war`.

```
alert(/^(wr|wR|au|u|a)$/.test(str));
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it works! :)
can you suggest me any good resource to learn REGEX, which is clean and detail??

Comment: @bharat http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great resource. To learn specifically about the JavaScript regex engine, see [MDN: Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @bharat There are suggested resources in the [tag:regex] tag info.